# Is it possible to parse only one JSON key/field/property in programming language C

Tags: c, json

Is it possible a C program to 'read' (by using C JSON parser) just one property of a JSON object stored in a char[]?
I want to read just one strig field of the JSON object, because I need to know its value to decide to what kind of **struct** to deserialize the whole JSON object.

I have tried to deserialize JSON objects containing only *int* and *double* types. I deserialize them to 'predefined' struct having such declaration for example:

```
struct obj{
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
};
```

But now I want to use two different structs for example:

```
struct obj1{
    int a;
    char b[40];
    double c;
    char d[15];
};

struct obj2{
    int a;
    struct in b;
    double c;
    char d[15];
};

struct in1{
   int ina;
   int inb;
   char inc[20];
};
```

Which structure to use to deserialize the JSON object is determined by the value of the 'string' **char d[15]**. And before deserializing the JSON I need to know its value.

The JSON string will be something like:

```
{"a":"...", "c":"pure string or another object", "c":"...", "d":"info about the type"}
```

I am confused because I think the C JSON parsers will be uncapable of doing this because they are not object oriented.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems pretty basic that if you can read everything in a JSON object, you can read one thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Most of the available C JSON Parsers provide a 'standart' C Struct, describing a single JSON value (key, property and so on...). If you make a variable of this type, it is possible to parse('read') a single value from a JSON object and then manipulate it or just use its value.